# multiline contents of a IO handle in haskell display nothing

Tags: haskell, io, createprocess

I have been experimenting with Haskell. I am trying to write a web crawler and I need to use external  curl  binary (due to some proxy settings, curl needs to have some special arguments which seem to be impossible/hard to set inside the haskell code, so i rather just pass it as a command line option. but that is another story...)

In the code at the bottom, if I change the marked line with `curl` instead of `curl --help` the output renders properly and gives:

```
"curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
"
```

otherwise the string is empty - as the `curl --help' response is multiline.
I suspect that in haskell the buffer is cleared with every new line. (same goes for other simple shell commands like *ls* versus *ls -l* etc.)

How do I fix it?

### The code:

```
import System.Process
import System.IO
main = do
    let sp = (proc "curl --help"[]){std_out=CreatePipe} -- *** THIS LINE ***
    (_,Just out_h,_,_)<- createProcess sp
    out <-hGetContents out_h
    print out
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`proc` takes as a first argument the name of the executable, not a shell command. That, is when you use `proc "foo bar"` you are not referring to a `foo` executable, but to an executable named exactly `foo bar`, with the space in its file name.

This is a *useful* feature in practice, because sometimes you do have spaces in there (e.g. on Windows you might have `c:\Program Files\Foo\Foo.exe`). Using a shell command you would have to escape spaces in your command string. Worse, a few other characters need to be escaped as well, and it's cumbersome to check what exactly those are. `proc` sidesteps the issue by not using the shell at all but passing the string as it is to the OS.

For the executable arguments, `proc` takes a separate argument list. E.g.

```
proc "c:\\Program Files\\Foo\\Foo.exe" ["hello world!%$"]
```

Note that the arguments need no escaping as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass arguments to `curl` you have to pass that it in the list:

```
sp = (proc "/usr/bin/curl" ["--help"]) {std_out=CreatePipe}
```

Then you will get the complete output in the entire string.